# Shortest Way to Merge JavaScript Objects Based on Path

Tags: javascript, object, lodash, javascript-objects

Anyone know how I could further condense my mergePath method, which merges keys on two objects based on a key/value path? My solution below uses Lodash.

```
let obj1 = { z: {fields: { a: "200", b: "2" }}}
let obj2 = { z: {fields: { a: "2", b: "20" }}}
let objsPath = "z.fields"

let mergePath = (objsPath, obj1, obj2) => (
  _.set(obj1, objsPath, {..._.get(obj1, objsPath), ..._.get(obj2, objsPath)})
)
```

Comment: Do you care whether you merge them in-place or is it really necessary to create the new object?

Comment: nope. either would be fine.

Comment: Then just do `_.merge(_.get(obj1, objsPath), _.get(obj2, objsPath))` (and return `obj1` if you want to put it in that `mergePath` function). Or use `Object.assign` instead of lodash `merge`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`_.merge()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#merge) to copy the path from `obj2` to `obj2`. Then you can return `obj1` (I've used the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)):

```js
const obj1 = { z: {fields: { a: "200", b: "2" }}}
const obj2 = { z: {fields: { a: "2", b: "20" }}}
const objsPath = "z.fields"

const mergePath = (objsPath, obj1, obj2) => (
  _.merge(_.get(obj1, objsPath), _.get(obj2, objsPath)), obj1
)

console.log(mergePath(objsPath, obj1, obj2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I could be mistaken, but isn't that technically a side-effect though?

Comment: But, it's an es6 arrow function that isn't wrapped in braces. so, it does an implicit return

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way without using external library

```js
const obj1 = { z: {fields: { a: "200", b: "2", c: "66" }}}
const obj2 = { z: {fields: { a: "2", b: "20" }}}

const mergedObj = {z: {fields: {}}}
Object.assign(mergedObj.z.fields ,obj1.z.fields, obj2.z.fields)

console.log(mergedObj)
```

Another way is using object spread operator but you need `babel preset` to use this feature - This is kind of **future syntax**. :)
That syntax will be like

```
const mergedObj = {
  z: {
    fields: {
      ...obj1.z.fields,
      ...obj2.z.fields
     }
   }
 }
```